# Adding Hash Tag Dynamically Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I am using a script to add a hash tag to the URL of the page. (I know I could just type the link as url.com/page.html#align-page but for users who come to the page without the hash tag I add it dynamically to direct them to the spot I want.)

I can see the hash tag added in the page URL but it sometimes goes to the correct div and other times it doesn't.

Why does this not work 100% of the time?

Here is the script (this script is in the `<head>`)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(function(){    

     window.location.hash = "align-page";

});
```

Note: The script is contained within the `$j(document).ready(function(){` as there are other scripts that are not listed here that are also within the `{  }`. If it needs to be placed outside of the `{ }` I can move it.

Also if there is a better way to do this with jQuery or another method I would welcome that.

Comment: Are you sure there is always a div with name or id `align-page`?

Comment: @some - Firefox 16, Chrome 21, IE 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(function(){    

     window.location = "#align-page";

});
```